# Log4Net logging to all appenders - how to target just one?

Tags: log4net

I have a C# app and when I try to direct log output to 1 log file, it writes to both log files.

c# code:

```
public static ILog log { get; set; }
log = LogManager.GetLogger("log1");
log.Info("foo");
```

app.config:

```
<log4net>

    <logger name="log1" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender1" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="log2" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender2" />
    </logger>

    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log1.txt" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender2" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="log2.log" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

This happens whether I try log1 or log2.  It writes to both regardless. 
Anyone know how to resolve this?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that is the config file in use? When I try that, nothing is logged and enabling log4net debugging shows the error `log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. AppenderSkeleton: No layout set for the appender named [RollingLogFileAppender1].` When I add a layout, it works as expected .

Comment: Shoot, I'm sorry, it looks like I culled some out for "easier" viewing.  I will edit it right now